C#, Sql, y Mostrar Datos
tardes, o noches. Mi duda es la siguiente
Yo tengo un programa en Visual Studio 2012 en C#
Tengo un formulario para registrar ventas conectada a una base de datos, el detalle es, que no sé cómo hacer cálculos matemáticos. Me explico:
Quisiera saber cómo puedo tomar los datos del numericUpDown y del textbox con el label 'Precio', para después calcularlos en un método o función, y de esta forma, mostrar en el textbox con el label 'subtotal', el subtotal (vaya la redundancia), en el textbox con el label 'IVA', multiplicar el subtotal con el IVA, y ya por el último, en el textbox con el label 'Total', mostrar el resultado del subtotal por el IVA
Soy principiante en esto, por ahora.

Si sirve de algo, dejaré escrito aquí lo que llevo de código.
ComandoInsertar.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Venta(id_Venta, codigo_producto, cantidad, precio, subtotal, iva, total) VALUES (@id_Venta, @codigo_producto, @cantidad, @precio, @subtotal, @iva, @total)";

        ComandoInsertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_producto", textBox1.Text);
        ComandoInsertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", numericUpDown1.Value);
        ComandoInsertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", textBox2.Text);


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Empecemos por partes... vs 2012 es tu ide, y no aporta a la pregunta. Si que version de c# usas, y para el caso, cual es tu framework de pantalla (parece winforms) ya que eso es lo que cambia la respuesta. Igual, lo que estas preguntando lo tenes contestado en la porcion de codigo que compartiste, que no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta.

Los estas tomando para pasarlos a la db.. que te impide hacer calculos con ellos?

Gracias por su retroalimentación usuario @gbianchi tomaré en cuenta sus comentarios.
Respecto a lo que usted me dijo, mi framework de pantalla es Windows Forms.
Respecto a lo segundo, estaba algo perdido en cuanto a la sintaxis, sin embargo, estoy trabajando en ello.
